# Opencv push_back function in Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I`m having serious problem.

```
class Set 
{ 
  Point_<int> point;    
  int val; 
  double *module; 
}; 

Mat m;
Set s;
m.push_back(s);
```

It says 
see reference to function template instantiation 'void cv::Mat::push_back(const _Tp &)' being compiled
When i add  after push_back it brings me:
see reference to class template instantiation 'cv::Mat_<_Tp>' being compiled

Answer (score 1):

Gotta admit that I'm not familiar with OpenCV, but reasoning from [this documentation](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_mat.html#af11e514b13395e44909ba5bb52a1295e), `push_back` member function of the `Mat` class seems to be a template function and it needs to know the type of the object you are going to "push back". So possibly try this:

```
m.push_back<Set>(s);
```

If doesn't work, the last suggestion would be

```
Mat<Set> m;
Set s;
m.push_back(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
#include<vector>
class Set 
{ 
  Point_<int> point;    
  int val; 
  double *module; 
}; 

std::vector<Set> m;
Set s;
m.push_back(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can push_back anything that is not OpenCV primitive types. Why not just use a STL container?